# Google Webmaster Tools & XML Generators claim page to be unreachable

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I recently made some changes to my website and wanted to inspect everything using google webmaster tools & update the sitemap using any site map generator i can find online.

However the sitemap generators **fail to connect** to my website and google claims the page to be **unreachable** i tried to remove my recently added .htaccess file but it didn't help

This is my .htaccess file which works fine for me. I can reach my page from all browsers with cleared cache etc ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^webdesign/(.*)$ /index.php?cl=$1
```

EDIT: Using Bing Webmaster Tools I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 07:16:56 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Set-Cookie: sec_session_id=bq05b1i45qerls9crr9pv1cgm7; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: lang=de; expires=Wed, 27-Jan-2016 07:16:56 GMT; Max-Age=86400
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.17
```

Comment: A downvote without at least a comment is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some research I got this fixed - actually the Bing Webmaster tools returned the needed hint.

The page actually always returned error  500 but still returned content. Browsers seem to ingore this - but the crawlers & tools don't.

Therefore the Problem was inside my code which caused the 500 result. With this info I was able to track it down and get it working again.